# VSCode C++ Terminal Process terminated with exit code: 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to use VSCode to do basic data sorting in C++, and needed to include a new library; while doing so, I think I accidentally screwed up something serious in the background (probably one of the .json files), because every time I try to build even the most basic programs with g++ through MinGW, I get the message "The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1. Even a basic "Hello World" project that I know works and previously made into an .exe, won't compile into an executable anymore.
**helloworld.cpp**

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout <<"Hello World!\n";
    
}
```

I tried restarting the window, reinstalling VSCode, starting a new project in a different directory, using the default json files in case I changed something I shouldn't have... I'm used to doing similar data tasks in FORTRAN through gfortran and Python with Spyder through Anaconda, but I'm inexperienced with both C++ and VSCode and am growing frustrated with the level of complexity to do something as simple as make a program run.

Any advice on how to fix this would be helpful; I've checked other similar questions, and no suggestion has worked.

**Tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17134.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(Windows) Launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Check the background stuffs logged in the **Debug Console** and add the details written after `Thread 1 hit breakpoint, main() ...`.

Comment: I'm not getting anything logged in the Debug Console at all;

from helloworld.cpp, I press Ctrl+Shift+P and enter C/C++: Build and debug active file, choose g++.exe, and a popup appears saying 'the preLaunchTask 'C/C++:g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code 1. 

Pressing 'show Errors' takes me to the (empty) Problems tab, while pressing 'debug anyway' generates another popup, saying 'launch:programs 'd:/C++/helloworld.exe' does not exist, which isn't surprising, and it prompts me to open launch.json.

Comment: Try to compile the program manually from the Command Prompt. Type: `g++ -o <program_name> <program_name>.c` and see if it compiles.

Comment: When I try to do anything in the Debug Console directly, it prints 'No debug adapter, can not send 'evaluate''.

Manually compiling in Command Prompt works, typing g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe

Comment: @drescherjm from what I understand, if the bug was in launch.json, the executable would be built but not successfully run; at the moment, the executable isn't even being built from within VSCode, though I can both compile and run helloworld.cpp successfully from Command prompt

Answer (score 0):

the problem for me was an error during the run time that the compiler didn't notice before. so you have to check if your script is fine even if no error is found by the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I was gone with same problem in case the exit code terminated with -1 as spend 2 hour then find that there is error in code as when I click on error button there is no error as I not get output as expected after seeing program so many I found that minor mistake in my program increase the complexity so I suggest check  each line of code file carefully ,in my case problem is solved by doing correction in code.